# IF cell contains WORD then extract WORD into another cell - Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large spreadsheet full of job titles that I need to sort in terms of seniority. I am trying to use an `IF (certain group of words are in cell) THEN (print that word)` function. I am relatively new to programming and have a vague idea of what I want my code to. Any other suggestions will be useful!

[image: Data set]

In the column next to the job title I would like to extract the relevant bits of information. In this case I am exploring the seniority of the role. Therefore I was hoping to extract words such as "head", "director", "CXO" where X is E/T/R/P etc. I was thinking about importing the data into python as we already have the data in CSV format but the issue is that there are commas within my CSV. I also think it would be best practice to do this within excel. Once I extracted the information I can then use a simple lookup function to relay if they are C-level, Manager level etc.

Comment: Give us an example of the data in your csv, and any code you've *already tried*

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The commas in your CSV file are delimiters.  Delimiters are separators - when you import data into an array for example, the commas separate the different elements.  The common way to put such a file into an excel array would be myArrayVariable = split(textVariable, ",")

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Rajiv, Please show us what is your expected output in the column

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
i = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
ans = InputBox("what needs to be checked", "test")
For K = 2 To i

If InStr(1, Range("A" & K).Value, ans) Then
Range("b" & K).Value = ans
End If
Next

End Sub
```

place text in col A, run the macro, macro will ask what to be searched, if found then will place in the B col, let us know if something like this works or any thing additional